# Finding a page created by a php function

Tags: php, html

I am trying to generate an HTML page using data gathered in a form on another page. I have this tag on the html page with the form:

```
<html>
<body>

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="private" > 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="vytran_css.css" />


<head> New Product Introduction </head>

<p> In order to begin the process of introducing a new product, please complete
the following form. Once you are satisfied with your responses to the various 
prompts, please click on the submit button at the bottom of the page. If you 
would like to start over, click the Reset button. If you have any questions, 
Please follow the link that says "Help".


<form action="html_data.php" id=from1 method="post"> 
Product Name: 
<input name="Name" size="20" type="text">
<br><br>

Project Lead Name:
<input name="PLname" size="20" type="text"> <br><br>

Team-members: <br>
<textarea name="Team-members" rows=10 cols=40 type="text"> </textarea> <br><br>

Product Type: <br>
<input name="Product Type" size="20" type="text"> <br><br>

Description: <br>
<textarea name="Description" rows=10 cols=40 type="text"> </textarea>
<br>

<br> <br>



<input value="Submit" type="submit" name="formSubmit">
<input value="Reset" type="reset">
<input value="Help" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='problems.html'">
</form>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and on the html_data.php page I have the following:

```
<?php 
    ob_start(); // start trapping output 
    $name = @$_POST['Name']; 
?> 
<html> 
<body> 
<p> 
Product Name: <?php echo $Name; ?><br> 
Project Lead: <?php echo $PLname; ?><br> 
Team Members: <?php echo $Team-members; ?><br> 
Description: <?php echo $Description; ?> 
</p> 
</body> 
</html> 
<?php 
    $output = ob_get_contents();  
    $newfile="output.txt";  
    $file = fopen ($newfile, "w");  
    fwrite($file, $output);  
    fclose ($file);   
    ob_end_clean();  
?>
```

This should do what I am asking it to do. The form submits with no problem, but I cannot find the page once it submits. Any idea what I need to change?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot find the page? Doesn't it show up in the browser? What web server are you using?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I cannot find the page once it submits" ? You say the form submits no problem. You mean the file you're writing to? You don't know the name of it? It's `output.txt`.

Comment: hmm $name and 'Name', 2 forms nested, is this your code?

Comment: `<form><form action="html_data.php" id=from1 method="post">`.  This is invalid HTML.  You can't have nested forms.

Comment: According to the IT people, we are using an IIS webserver.

Comment: @ChelseaCerame: What *exactly* is your problem?  What can't you find?  What are looking for?  What are you doing?

Comment: Yes, a form in a form where the top form is empty? Also you didn't close the forms.

Comment: By not being able to find the page, I mean that it doesn't show up under my set of documents.

Comment: I have no idea as to what the `goal` is here. Doesn't show up in your set of documents, the `output.txt` file?

Comment: @Rocket I am trying to find the html file that should have been generated

Comment: I see no reference to `html` here. If there's another piece of `code` you're not showing us, then no one can help you further.

Comment: @ChelseaCerame: It's in `output.txt`.  It should be in the same folder as `html_data.php`.  Check the permissions on that folder, maybe the script can't write the file.

Comment: @Fred I just edited to show all of the html page

Comment: @Rocket, looks like I can't write to that folder. I'm going to email our IT guy to get permissions. Thank you!

Comment: I tested your form and it generates a `0` (zero) for `$Team-members`. I renamed it to `$Team_members` for both instances, and it made the entry correctly. These are my findings so far.

Comment: Addendum: If you're looking to see the output to screen, add `echo $output;` underneath `ob_end_clean();`

Comment: Plus, if you want to save it as a `HTML` page, change your filename with the `.htm` extension; just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your form**

Change from

`<textarea name="Team-members" rows=10 cols=40 type="text">`

to

`<textarea name="Team_members" rows=10 cols=40 type="text">`

In your **html_data.php**

Change from

`<?php echo $Team-members; ?>`
**to**
`<?php echo $Team_members; ?>`

There is **obviously an issue with the dash** between Team and members.

- PHP is treating the hyphen as a mathematical operation, being a minus.
- I.e.: Team **minus** members

Then, if you wish to `echo` the data to screen after submission, add

```
echo $output;
```

underneath `ob_end_clean();`

**This worked for me.**

Comment: That figures. "A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores." Hyphens aren't allowed in variable names.

Comment: STYLING: If you want to `append` to file use the `a+` directive. Plus, if you wish to add some styling to it, name your file with either the `.shtml` or `.php` extension and put an `include` file right off the bat at the top, such as `<!--#include virtual="./included_file.shtml" -->` or `PHP` equivalent and in it, put any styling content or additional header you would like to appear.